# Cytoscape.js set node active programmatically

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js

I need to set node selected inside my function where I create it

```
cy.on('tap', function (e) {
    if (!e.target.id) {
        let x = e.position.x;
        let y = e.position.y;
        let new_node = {group: "nodes", data: {id: x + '_' + y}, position: {x: x, y: y}};
        cy.add(new_node);
        // make node selected (click on it)
    }
});
```

Then i will get created node data like I get it from other nodes

```
selected = cy.$('node:selected').jsons();
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was simple. I added **selected: true** to initialisation

```
let new_node = {group: "nodes", data: {id: x + '_' + y}, position: {x: x, y: y}, selected: true};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`let new_node = {group: "nodes", data: {id: x + '_' + y}, position: {x: x, y: y},classes : 'selected'};`

and then

`cy.$('node.selected')`

Comment: It's bad solution for me, because I use :selected state everywhere and I need to overwrite it's behavior for class

Comment: There is no a lot difference with your answer you are still controlling with new  property. And usually selection is done with css class to manipulate node style.

Comment: yes, there is no big difference. Your answer helped me to think in another direction and I found the solution that is good for my case, thank you!

Comment: Glad that it helped.